# Case sensitivity in windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, case-sensitive, uppercase

Quick question:

Are there an circumstances where a command must be in uppercase or lowercase in a windows batch file? Apart from options/switches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only the metavariable (loop-control variable) in a `for` loop is case-sensitive AFAIAA. Note that `set` string-replacement suffers the opposite problem - it is case-insensitive for the string-to-be-replaced.